# Why my Eclipse doesn't mark the reserverd words for Haskell?

Tags: eclipse, haskell, ghc

I've installed the plugin for Eclipse Luna: EclipseFP -  http://eclipsefp.sf.net/updates . Its Works, but the IDE is not marking the reserved words.

[image]

Comment: AFAIK eclipseFP is not maintained anymore so you might be out of luck (see https://github.com/JPMoresmau/eclipsefp)

Answer (score 2):

That looks like you are actually using the normal text editor.

Close the file and then right click on the file in Project Explorer and choose 'Open With...' and select the Haskell editor.

Eclipse remembers the last editor you used to open a file so if you had opened this file before installing the plug-in you will get the plain text editor. Once you have opened the file with the correct editor it will use that editor by default in future.